Pytesseract OCR not recognizing digits in clean binary image
I want to recognize a hadwritten digit in a binary image.
I planned on using tesseract ocr, but I could never get the accuracy above 50%. Here is a part of the code I used:
plt.imshow(roi,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, config='--psm 10')
print(text)

And the image drawn:
digit_4
The text was incorrect most of the time - in the case above, it was '+'. Other incorrect answers included '4.', 'UL', and 'A'. I originally had
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, config='--psm 10 digits')
but removed the digits setting after seeing half of the text come out as blank.

How can I improve the accuracy?
Why does the ocr output multiple characters when it is set to recognize a single character?

(I am using version 4.1.1 pytesseract)
